# Can I make a progress bar like where the value is just a little image that travels to the end of progress bar in Godot?

Tags: progress-bar, game-development, godot, texture2d

Can I make a progress bar like where the value is just a little image that travels to the end of progress bar in Godot?

I was trying to do something like this:

[When value is %0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9Qdx.png)

[When value is %50](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsEph.png)

[When value is %100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdqvP.png)

If anyone who knows some way to do this without framing every possible value, please tell me how.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new scene, with a line2d as its root, and a sprite (with whatever texture you want) as its child. You can set up the line with [these](https://pasteboard.co/CHslEoQuC8dR.png) properties and could set the image like [so](https://pasteboard.co/32MQYN6hZm0g.png). Then all you would need to do is attach a script to the line and increment the x position of the sprite over time. I wrote a script example for you here, but depending on your use case you may want to adjust some things or make some of the variables dynamic.

```
extends Line2D
var maxSteps = 100
var count = 0
var step = 1
onready var sprite = get_node("Sprite")

func do_step():
    if count < maxSteps:
        sprite.global_position.x += step
        count += step
```